# Error: jar not found in bash after installing OpenJDK

Tags: linux, debian, java

I installed openJDK.   `java -version`

> OpenJDK Runtime Env. IcedTea6 1.13.4 (...) 
>   OpenJDK Client VM (build23.25...)

when I execute `jar xvf myfile.war` I get error:

> bash: jar : command not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I failed to notice that I had installed `openjdk-7-jre` when what I really wanted was `openjdk-7-jdk` (**jdk)**.  Note that `java -version` returns

> OpenJDK Runtime Env. IcedTea6 1.13.4 (...) 
>   OpenJDK Client VM (build23.25...)

...with no mention of the JDK in either case (it doesn't tell you if the JDK is installed, only the JRE).